# Getting 12501 error ,after first googe sign in attempt

Tags: android, kotlin

i am integrating Google-Sign in API in my android project, it works perfectly except that it does nothing after picking up the user email, when i debugged i found out that it returns error with code of 12501, However, when i click the sign-in button again it doesn't show the emails dialog, but instead it logs in perfectly. the code:

the click handler

```
   googleLogin.setOnClickListener{
        firebaseAuthUtil.defaultGoogleLogin(this)
    }
```

the defaultGoogle Login method

```
   fun defaultGoogleLogin(cxt:Context){
    val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
        .requestProfile()
        .requestEmail()
        .requestIdToken(cxt.getString(R.string.google_client_id))
        .build()

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(cxt,gso)
    var signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.signInIntent
    if(googleDefaultLauncher != null) {
        googleDefaultLauncher!!.launch(signInIntent)
    }

}
```

the registerActivityLauncher (e.g googleDefaultLauncher)

```
   val googleRegistry = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){

    val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(it.data);
    getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF, MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean(GOOGLE_TAP_SIGNIN,true).apply()
    Log.d("LogINActivity","email"+task.result!!.email!!)
    firebaseAuthUtil.handleSignInResult(this,task)
}
```

finally the handleSignInMethod

```
 fun handleSignInResult(cxt:Context,task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
    //causes error Log.d("FirebaseAuthUtil",task.result.toString())
    try {
        Log.d("FirebaseAuthUtil","HandleSignINResult")
        val account: GoogleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        auth.signInWithCredential(GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(account.idToken,null)).addOnCompleteListener {
            var updateProfile = UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
            updateProfile.photoUri = account.photoUrl
            updateProfile.displayName = account.displayName
            auth.currentUser!!.updateProfile(updateProfile.build())
            auth.currentUser!!.updateEmail(account.email!!)
        }


    } catch (e: ApiException) {
        // The ApiException status code indicates the detailed failure reason.
        // Please refer to the GoogleSignInStatusCodes class reference for more information.
        Log.w("Google", "signInResult:failed code=" + e.statusCode+ e.message+"local"+e.localizedMessage)

    }catch (e1 : IllegalArgumentException){
        Toast.makeText(cxt,"Sorry, we couldn't sign you in with your google account",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```

My Attempts:

I double checked the SHA-1 finger prints and it's correct,
I double checked the client server id and it's correct,
when i logged the **GoogleSignInAccount** task, (the task i pass to handleSignInResult) it isn't null neither empty.

Appreciate your help